# rename the columns name after cbind the data

Tags: r, rename

[image]

```
merger <- cbind(as.character(Date),weather1$High,weather1$Low,weather1$Avg..High,weather1$Avg.Low,sale$Scanned.Movement[a])
```

After `cbind` the data, the new DF has column names automatically `V1`, `V2`...... 
I want rename the column by

```
colnames(merger)[,1] <- "Date"
```

but failed. And when I use `merger$V1` ,

```
Error in merger$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can also name columns directly in the `cbind` call, e.g.

```
cbind(date=c(0,1), high=c(2,3))
```

Output:

```
     date high
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    1    3
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but somehow only the first column name was used in my case, the subsequent column names were ignored...

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(cbind(date=c(0,1), high=c(2,3)))`.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
colnames(merger)[1] <- "Date"
```

### Example

Here is a simple example:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- cbind(a, a, a)
colnames(b)

# change the first one
colnames(b)[1] <- "abc"

# change all colnames
colnames(b) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
```

Comment: @ jimsigner  I tried that and says: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Comment: can you provide an reproducible mini example?

Answer (score 6):

you gave the following example in your question:

```
colnames(merger)[,1]<-"Date"
```

the problem is the comma: colnames() returns a vector, not a matrix, so the solution is:

```
colnames(merger)[1]<-"Date"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you pass only vectors to `cbind()` it creates a matrix, not a dataframe. Read `?data.frame`.

Answer (score 4):

A way of producing a `data.frame` and being able to do this in one line is to coerce all matrices/data frames passed to `cbind` into a data.frame while setting the column names attribute using `setNames`:

```
a = matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 2)
b = matrix(runif(10), ncol = 2)

cbind(setNames(data.frame(a), c('n1', 'n2')), 
      setNames(data.frame(b), c('u1', 'u2')))
```

which produces:

```
          n1        n2         u1        u2
1 -0.2731750 0.5030773 0.01538194 0.3775269
2  0.5177542 0.6550924 0.04871646 0.4683186
3 -1.1419802 1.0896945 0.57212043 0.9317578
4  0.6965895 1.6973815 0.36124709 0.2882133
5  0.9062591 1.0625280 0.28034347 0.7517128
```

<del>Unfortunately, there is no `setColNames` function analogous to `setNames`</del> for data frames that returns the matrix after the column names, however, there is nothing to stop you from adapting the code of `setNames` to produce one:

```
setColNames <- function (object = nm, nm) {
    colnames(object) <- nm
    object
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377295/setnames-equivalent-for-colnames-and-rownames-in-r), the `magrittr` package contains functions for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you offer `cbind` a set of arguments all of whom are vectors, you will get not a dataframe, but rather a matrix, in this case an all character matrix. They have different features. You can get a dataframe if some of your arguments remain dataframes, Try:

```
merger <- cbind(Date =as.character(Date),
             weather1[ , c("High", "Low", "Avg..High", "Avg.Low")] , 
             ScnMov =sale$Scanned.Movement[a] )
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy just add the name which you want to use in quotes before adding 
   vector

```
a_matrix <- cbind(b_matrix,'Name-Change'= c_vector)
```