# setNames equivalent for colnames and rownames for use in pipe

Tags: r, magrittr

I often use R's `setNames` function in a magrittr pipeline or elsewhere to fix the names of an object on the fly:

```
library(magrittr)
mytable %>% setNames(c("col1", "col2", "col3")) %>% ...[more analysis]
```

Are there equivalent functions for colnames and rownames? Something like `setColnames`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`magrittr` provides several "aliases" (see `??Aliases`), including `set_colnames` (equivalent to `` `colnames<-` ``) and `set_rownames` (equivalent to `` `rownames<-` ``).

Answer (score 6):

It’s not pretty, but the following works:

```
mytable %>% `colnames<-`(c("col1", "col2", "col3")) %>% ...[more analysis]
```

This uses the fact that an assignment of the form `colnames(x) <- foo` is actually calling a function `` `colnames<-`(x, foo) ``. The backticks around the name are necessary since `colnames<-` is not ordinarily a valid identifier in R (but between backticks it is).

So you don’t need any aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `setNames()` can be used if the object is converted to a data frame.  The following uses the new R pipe operator:

```
    matrix(1:6, ncol=2) |> as.data.frame() |>
        setNames(c("One23","Four56")) -> thatsIt
```

The right pointing assignment arrow seems more in the spirit of pipes than a preceding left pointing assignment arrow.  Or, to print the result:

```
    matrix(1:6, ncol=2) |> as.data.frame() |>
        setNames(c("One23","Four56")) |> print()
      One23 Four56
    1     1      4
    2     2      5
    3     3      6
```